# Using node-localize

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, angularjs, localization

What is the best way to provide localization with Node.js and AngularJS stack?

I am trying to provide localization using [node-localize](https://github.com/AGROSICA/node-localize) module. The front end is AngularJS and Node server acts a REST service only providing JSON strings.

In the documentation of node-localize, it was written we can pass a folder and all translations.json files will be used for translation. But I am unable to get this working with files. What should be format of translations.json? I want to pass the entire file to Angular and using filters want to implement localization in views (as [explained here](http://codingsmackdown.tv/blog/2012/12/14/localizing-your-angularjs-app/)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me, basically just use the same JSON that you would normally pass into the constructor:

tranlations.js

```
 var Localize = require('localize');

 var myLocalize = new Localize('./translations/');

 console.log(myLocalize.translate("Testing...")); // Testing...
 console.log(myLocalize.translate("Substitution: $[1]", 5)); // Substitution: 5

 myLocalize.setLocale("es");
 console.log(myLocalize.translate("Testing...")); // Pruebas...

 myLocalize.setLocale("sr");
 console.log(myLocalize.translate("Substitution: $[1]", 5)); // замена: 5
```

./translations/translations.json

```
 {
     "Testing...": {
         "es": "Pruebas...",
         "sr": "тестирање..."
     },
     "Substitution: $[1]": {
         "es": "Sustitución: $[1]",
         "sr": "замена: $[1]"
     }
 }
```

Then to execute:

`node translations.js`

Comment: Thank you :)
Would you suggest any other npm modules for my use case - node (only JSON output, doesn't send jade files) & angular?

Comment: @Nitin this seems to work pretty well, but I haven't tested others.